# Keeping 2D object proportions in Game View: unreliable code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm keeping proportions of a sprite always the same while moving it on Z axis (with cursor) in Game View.
My code

```
float dist = ((Camera.main.transform.position - mySprite.transform.position).magnitude);
float startSize = Mathf.Abs(1 / Camera.main.transform.position.z);
Vector3 realScale = myDict[mySprite.name];
dim = new Vector3((dist * realScale.x), (dist * realScale.y), (dist * realScale.z)) * startSize;
mySprite.transform.localScale = dim;
```

(Since the localScale of the object can be changed in scene edit I store its values before entering Game View by putting them in myDict Dictionary.)
Currently I do not use this code in Update but I call it by a editor button.
At first it would seem to work well but then I realized that in fact it is not accurate.
I did several tests by cutting images from a background and turning them into sprites.
The sprite overlaid the original image is always slightly larger.
I could multiply the values of Scale for a constant but it does not seem to me the right way.
Can you direct me?

Comment: @TehMightyPotato, I saw you have corrected layout of my code and I accepted your change, thanks. But as for my question, would you have more targeted suggestions? I've really looked on the StackOverflow and Unity forums but maybe I'm missing the search keys, I've found something similar but it keeps fixed size sprite moving the camera back and forth. I would need to maintain fixed dimensions by moving the sprite with a fixed camera. I did not say it but obviously the projection is Perspective.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not really clear to me what you are trying to do. You are moving a sprite and want to keep its proportions. But how should they be changed in the first place? If you just move your sprite it shouldn't alter its scale or its proportions.

Comment: Maybe I explained bad because English is not my native language. If you move a sprite in Scene View, it apparently gets bigger by moving it closer to the camera, and smaller by moving it away. Same behavior will be in Game View. In my editor I move the sprites in Game View and I would like them to keep the same original size in whatever position Z they are. My code above does just that but lacks something. Imagine having a 2D background and a sprite cut from it. When you position sprite on the Z axis in Game View, you would like it to be the same size as the image from which you cut it.

Comment: Okay now I get it. You should edit your question to incorporate that.
I'm guessing a orthographic view is no option?

Comment: Unfortunately I need perspective projection. But I know it can be done, long ago I found a post somewhere but I can not find it anymore.